# Displaying multiple videos with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display 9 videos onto their own canvases using Tkinter. The problem I am running into is that the window is very laggy and unresponsive. This means nothing else can be done in the application whilst the videos are playing.

I have tried to use a second thread to perform steps 1-3 (as shown below), but this does not seem to help. I am struggling to see how I can make this process more efficient and any help would be much appreciated.

My process for doing this is as follows:

1. Read the video using cv2

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
```

2. Read a frame from the video

```py
cap.set(1, frame_num)
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

3. Resize and convert to PhotoImage

```py
frame = imutils.resize(frame, height=video_height, width=video_width)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(frame))
```

4. Draw the image to canvas

```py
im = self.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor=NW)
```

This is done for all 9 videos, every 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for this is to buy a computer with more CPU cores / GPU / faster CPU, i'm afraid ! If the videos are displayed on a small canvas, you should resize them before playing them. That is, have a already resized video and play that instead of the original one. Reading frame by frame, then resizing and displaying on canvas the frame is very CPU expensive, already for one video, and you do it with 9 ! Thats why the GUI becomes laggy : Your CPU uses *all* its resources for resizing and playing, and has almost nothing left for responding  to user events. A GPU would help there : it takes the part of resizing, which is the most CPU expensive.